# Laravel - User foreign key resulting in trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Intro**

Dear Stackers,

I am currently working on an small project thats rather taking me a large sum of time. This is inefficient production, and thus I want to get my problem solved. So, what's the problem?

**The problem**

I am trying to access a property inside the $hour variable. This property is the "name" field of the User model (The model provided to you by Laravel's Default Install). The User and Hour models are linked together through "werknemer_id" inside the Hour table which references to the "id" field inside the User table. When I try to call upon the user however, it returns me a "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

**Database relationship**
https://gyazo.com/5a39f76d7fe6e297551e74a46a8def7c

**User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Hour;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

public function Hours() {
    return $this->hasMany(Hour::class);
}

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

**Hour Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class Hour extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'werknemer_id', 'weeknummer', 'dag', 'uren', 'toelichting',
];

public function User() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```

**Hour Migration Table**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateHoursTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('hours', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('werknemer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('weeknummer');
        $table->string('dag');
        $table->integer('uren');
        $table->string('toelichting');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('hours', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('werknemer_id')->references('id')->on('users');   
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('hours');
}
}
```

**The view**

```
<a href="{{ url('/uren/create') }}">Voeg je uren toe</a>
<br/>
<table class="display table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive dynamic-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Werknemer</th>
            <th>Week</th>
            <th>Dag</th>
            <th>Aantal uren</th>
            <th>Toelichting</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>


    enter code here


        @foreach($hours as $hour)
        <tr class="clickable-row" data-url="/uren/{{ $hour->id }}">
            {{dd($hour)}}
            <td>{{ $hour->User->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $hour->weeknummer }}</td>
            <td>{{ $hour->dag }}</td>
            <td>{{ $hour->uren }}</td>
            <td>{{ $hour->toelichting }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ url('/uren', array('id' => $hour->id)) }}">Laat zien</td>
            <td><a href="{{ url('/uren/' . $hour->id . '/edit') }}">Bijwerken</a></td>
            {!! Form::open(array('route' => array('uren.destroy', $hour->id), 'method' => 'delete')) !!}
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger"  data-toggle="confirmation"   type="submit"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Verwijder</button></td>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
           </tr>
           @endforeach

    </tbody>

    </table>
    <a href="/home">Keer terug naar het dashboard.</a>
```

**The view, with $hour dd'd**

```
Hour {#200 ▼
  #fillable: array:6 [▼
    0 => "id"
    1 => "werknemer_id"
    2 => "weeknummer"
    3 => "dag"
    4 => "uren"
    5 => "toelichting"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "werknemer_id" => 1
    "weeknummer" => 5
    "dag" => "Wednesday"
    "uren" => 5
    "toelichting" => ""
    "remember_token" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-02-01 08:56:10"
    "updated_at" => "2017-02-01 08:56:10"
  ]
  #original: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "werknemer_id" => 1
    "weeknummer" => 5
    "dag" => "Wednesday"
    "uren" => 5
    "toelichting" => ""
    "remember_token" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-02-01 08:56:10"
    "updated_at" => "2017-02-01 08:56:10"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

**The actual result if the dd is left out**

https://gyazo.com/73a83f411728084b5b09e806132ed76e?token=2a47870927ce239b03763c8dc24384a5

Comment: share var_dump($hours);

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5fc0a0654cad9beedd23c6db6c03e100 - Doesin't renders; just throws the error.

Comment: do var_dump($hours); exit; .... also if you share what is at line no 20 ?

Comment: <td><?php echo e($hour->User->name); ?></td>

And about the var_dump($hours); --> I am running it in the view, using blade's templating engine: 

https://gyazo.com/56027ff3457673f85c174762524bad6b

Comment: https://gyazo.com/71f39deaad03b36771606f0862aca4c7 --- Var_dump

Comment: share the code where you setting value in hours variable .....must be in controller that u not shared here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your naming. Laravel has a naming convention it expects you to follow, if you don't, you have to let the system know.

In your hours model, you have this the User function like so:

```
    public function User() {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

It expects your foreign key to be user_id not werknemer_id. To rectify this, add the id as a second arg

```
    public function User() {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'werknemer_id');
    }
```

or

```
    public function werknemer() {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/635cd1d8e489f92be3623513f0f47862 --- FIXED --- Thank you very much, Fatimah.